# How to emphasize the roles & responsibilities I performed in my org on my resume?

Tags: resume, careers

Say, I've been working on a project named "XYZ" in my org. 
How can I at best list the responsibilities/skills I performed/learnt for it on my resume?

- Is it proper to give away the name of the project ?
- Even if it is,how to ensure that the prospective employer can fully
  understand the domain of the project I've listed? Do I even need
  to worry about it?
- Will it be good to list the rating I got during the performance
  review(as a testament to me being a hard, efficient worker) ?

Answer (score 2):

R11G - The name of a project will likely mean nothing to an interviewer. Unless the project name is widely known outside of your company, don't bother including it. "The Apollo Lunar Landing Module Project" would be good to include. "The Tiger Project" likely would not.

What you want to do is list the salient features of that project and your responsibilities for them, such that they are helpful for the role for which you are applying.

> Managed a 2-year project designed to increase sales into the
>   Government sector. Responsible for budgeting, hiring, training... etc,
>   etc

Unless the "rating" you received is such that people outside your company will understand it completely, it may not be helpful. "Received a 'Top 10 Salesman' rating" would be useful where "Attained a 'Good Job' rating" might not.

In short, within your resume you should concentrate on the roles and responsibilities and not so much on the names of the projects and the names of the ratings.

You can use the cover letter to highlight more specifics if and only if they are relevant for the new job.

And use the interview itself to expound on the details of the project that make you a particularly appealing candidate.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you with an outline:

- Title
- Company
- Year
- Project Name

  - Detail
  - Detail
  - Detail
- Project Name...

Only do this if you were involved in at least 2 projects and can say 2 or 3 things about each. Then to go off of Joe Strazzere's answer focus on tangibles.

Instead of saying for example:

> Led the team to complete the project

Figure out what the deadline was and when it was completed and then word it similar to:

> 20% faster project completion than expected.

Same thing with Budget. On a 2 year project does the company generally have some employee turn-over? Was your turn-over rate less? Communicate that. End of the day these are the types of things that are most important to be communicating.